# Getting call info from Skype in Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, skype

I writing my windows service app and need to get info about skype process and skype status, like - is user on call, and etc.

Now I'm getting only process info

Like this

```
public static ApplicationData GetProcessSkype()
    {
        var skypeProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("SkypeApp").FirstOrDefault();
        if (skypeProcess != null)
        {
            var skypeData = new ApplicationData
            {
                Id = skypeProcess.Id,
                //EndTime = skypeProcess.ExitTime,
                StartTime = skypeProcess.StartTime,
                MachineName = skypeProcess.MachineName,
                PeakPagedMemorySize = skypeProcess.PeakPagedMemorySize,
                PeakPagedMemorySize64 = skypeProcess.PeakPagedMemorySize64
            };
            return skypeData;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Any info about, how to get skype status, do they have some kind of API, etc?

Comment: You know that you can't get info on activity in user's desktop sessions from service's one, don't you? You may want to [edit] the question to narrow it down on what you don't know.

Comment: Okay. Main question, can I access call info from Windows Service. If not directly, what I need to do, in which side I need to look to make this. @AlexeiLevenkov